# How to compare two videos and get timestamp(s) of differing frame(s)?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, comparison

I've got rips of two copies of the same physical DVD. There's a difference between the two disc images - one of the videos files has a small binary diffence. I suspect one of the discs has physical damage which is causing one of the rips to have the slight difference/corruption. I'd like to find out if there are visual differences between the two video files, and if so, at what timestamps the visual differences are at. I'd then compare those frames to see if either of the videos has any corrupted-looking frames, in order to determine which copy of the video is corrupted and which one (probably) isn't.

It seems like using ffmpeg's framehash can be used to find frames that differ, but I'm not sure how to then view the specific frames - the framehash output doesn't have timestamps, just dts and pts values.

Comment: It is more likely that the compression settings or codec used is different, but the frames are the same. This will result in an image, that looks the same to the naked eye, but if you compare, will tell you every frame is different.

Comment: @LPChip This isn't the case. The two video files are the same other than a few bytes, and the first few frames I manually checked are 1:1 identical. The source of the files is basically the same - the DVD master that the DVD manufacturer used.

Comment: You could decode the file. If there are any decoding errors ffmpeg will output error messages: `ffmpeg -i input -f null -`

Comment: Well that would help in this case that there are "formal" errors in the video, but I'm looking to do a side by side comparison of the differing frames/audio.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the method I use to compare two videos, based on the info from some different webpages. If anyone knows any better / faster / more optimal way then please let me know. :)

**Step 1:** I'm creating the additional video - a "summary" of two videos I want to compare:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i in1.mp4 -i in2.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]format=yuva444p,lut=c3=128,negate[video2withAlpha],[0:v][video2withAlpha]overlay[out]" -map [out] -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy out.mp4
```

If the frames in `in1.mp4` and `in2.mp4` are the same then this command will produce "almost perfectly" grey frame in `out.mp4`. If the input frames are different then the output frame will have "some" distortions.

**Step 2:** Now it is the time to find these distorted frames in `out.mp4`:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i out.mp4 -filter_complex "select='gt(scene,0.001)',drawtext=fontfile='arial.ttf':text='%{pts\:hms}':x=(w-tw)/2:y=h-(2*lh):fontcolor=white:fontsize=30" -vsync 0 "frames/frame-%05d.jpg"
```

Distorted frames will be exported to separate jpg files, saved in the subfolder and marked with a timestamp at their bottom (you can change the position, font, size and color of the timestamp).

Here is the tricky part: `gt(scene,0.001)` - that `0.001` defines "sensitivity" to detect distorted frames. In most cases value of `0.001` works ok for me but you can change that in any direction (lesser value means better sensitivity so it will generate more frames).

Comment: Solution provided doesn't seem to work anymore. I get "no matches found: [out]" with ffmpeg 6.0.